# SVG not displaying text on Chrome in PHP

Tags: google-chrome, svg, cross-browser

My PHP code displays the text over SVG. When I use IE and Firefox everything is fine, but on Chromium I just get a picture without text.

```
<?php
    echo "<svg width='1100' height='1620'>";
    $text = "Some text to be shown";

    echo "<text x=473  y=81 font-family='Verdana' font-size='18' fill='black'>
                  <a xlink:href='index.php'>
                  <a href='index.php'>$text</a></a>
            </text>";

echo "</svg>";
?>
```

Comment: Instead of showing us the PHP side, show us the output that the browser receives. This isn't really a PHP problem. Looks like it could be an interesting browser issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing `<a xlink:href='index.php'>` and it's corresponding `</a>`?

Comment: That's it. Everything is OK now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $text needs to be concatenated?

```
echo "<text x=473  y=81 font-family='Verdana' font-size='18' fill='black'>
              <a xlink:href='index.php'>
              <a href='index.php'>" . $text . "</a></a>
        </text>";
```

Comment: I did what you said, but the result is the same. On IE and Firefox everything is fine, but on Chromium still nothing.

Comment: What kind of error in the developer console are you getting? @user1043939

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `<a xlink:href` is needed. Try this.

https://jsfiddle.net/tsekgemo/

```
<div id="parent">
    <svg width='1100' height='1620'>
        <text x=473 y=81 font-family='Verdana' font-size='18' fill='black'>
            <a href='index.php'>Some text to be shown</a>
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG text with nested link doesn't work in chrome browser, this is how your code suppose look like:

```
<?php
echo "<svg>
   $text = "Some text to be shown";

    echo "<text x=473  y=81 font-family='Verdana' font-size='18' fill='black'>
                   <a xlink:href='index.php'></a>
                    <a href='index.php'>$text</a>
              </text>";
echo </svg>
```

?>